# How curses differs Enter from Ctrl+Enter and other key strokes with overlapping escape sequences?

Tags: terminal, curses, ansi-escape

As far as I can see, in `Konsole` both `CTRL+ENTER` and `ENTER` look like byte `13` in the `stdin` of the running app. But when I run `mc` which obviously uses `ncurses` lib, pressing `CTRL+ENTER` inserts the name of the file into the command line while `ENTER` opens the file. How is it implemented? I tried to look into sources, but they are totally unreadable for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528091/ncurses-trapping-extended-keys-control-left-shift-function-etc ?

Comment: not quite - I'll try to answer it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mc` (midnight commander) doesn't use ncurses for *input*, but may use it for *output*.  Essentially it is looking for specific character sequences.

`mc` makes little use of the terminfo database, essentially only to check on the xterm mouse- and alternate-screen features.

In principle, it *could* read the user-defined capabilities from the ncurses terminfo database (see for example [ncurses trapping extended keys (Control-left, Shift-Function etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528091/ncurses-trapping-extended-keys-control-left-shift-function-etc)), but it does *not*.

Since you are looking at sources, see the source of `mc`, in `lib/tty/key.c`, which contains tables which `mc` uses as a set of predefined keys.  Doing it that way "works" when `mc` is configured to use slang, for instance, though it has the drawback that it's hardcoded and may not actually match your terminal.

However - as I said, `mc` does its own *input*.  Further down in `key.c`, you may see a chunk in `get_modifier()` ifdef'd with `HAVE_TEXTMODE_X11_SUPPORT`.  Inside that is a call which ultimately goes to [`XQueryPointer`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryPointer.html), which `mc` uses to find the current state of the modifier keys — if it happens to be running in an X display, and if the feature is enabled.  You are probably seeing that.